# If any meaning to life is bad, then is all life bad?

Tags: meaning-of-life, values

If any meaning to life is bad, then is all life bad? What is the relation between the meaning of life and life?

Comment: Any meaning to life is bad cannot be. Eg according to existenteliasm people have a lot of freedom in setting ther own meanings (so they can set good meanings if they choose so)

Comment: i agree more or less @NikosM. i probably think that if meaning is bad then only things external to what that is the meaning of (life) can be good, but i am unclear about the basic jargon there

Comment: [The Meaning of Life](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/life-meaning/): "what, if anything, makes life meaningful" i.e. valued. So what does it mean to say that "any meaning to life is bad"?

Comment: it could amount to e.g. a subjective preference for a life that appears meaningless to me or others, that lacks the sort of things we usually associate with "meaning". i probably don't think value = meaning, at least under analysis.

Comment: @CLEMON i would propose to read about existentialism. As they say "crises of meaning makes us all existentialists in the final analysis"

Comment: "The truly adult view, by contrast, is that our life is as meaningful, as full and as wonderful as we choose to make it." would you say that entails our life is as valuable as we make it and nothing more? that puts a lot of weight on our agency, almost in a stoic sense.

Comment: @CLEMON existentialists recognize that agents have certain freedom and can use it. Existenbtialists also recognize facticity, that is what is at any given time as given. Balancing the two makes authenticity

Comment: i definitely think we need not claim that only meaning is valuable. is absolutely every desired object meaningful? that itself looks meaningless, just as the claim that only moral value has meaning seems a little sparse

Comment: i am far too distressed to worry over whether i'm free right now @NikosM. what do you make of that? anyway, i think we can lose meaning and not value, and vice versa, that finding meaning in e.g. suffering is not the same as finding it valuable. reads a bit like a discurisve claim, that all interpretation is as good

Comment: @CLEMON it is up to you to say. But personally I want to be free to set my own meaning and value instead of them being imposed upon me. None of us is omnipotent, but recognizing our situated freedom can be liberating (even if only indirectly)

Comment: i would be unclear in what way i am free without reading about it, except concretely (i am not free to spend this nickel)

Comment: @CLEMON hope all the best! Read [Existence precedes essence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existence_precedes_essence) as a start.

Answer (score 0):

No. All life is not bad just because one experiences bad in life.

Hedonism is the idea that pleasure in life is good and pain is bad. Then maximum pleasure is the greatest good. Hedonism is criticized because some modes of pleasure cause long term disability and subsequent loss of life or pleasure. Or some modes of pain cause the restoration of vital pleasure. One example is using crystalized lead to make water sweet in ancient Rome. The sweet taste causes pleasure and the lead causes disability and death via heavy metal poisoning. Another example is scrubbing and cleaning an infected wound or enduring some other painful medical procedure to remedy some disability and restore vitality. Examples like this only operate to show the active observer of one's own emotions that long term vital-pleasure, the ability to live without persistent pain and with elevated or exalted pleasure, is also a hedonistic value!

I define vitality as life and the ability to live. Baruch Spinoza defines an affect (emotion) as a feeling of desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. In this context a rational mammal would value the causes of vital-pleasure as good and the causes of disability-pain as bad.

Spinoza defines desire as appetite accompanied by consciousness thereof. Then if the body desires to gain and keep vital-pleasure it needs the vital cognitive ability to value the good and judge the good. And if the body desires to avoid disability-pain it needs the vital cognitive ability to value the good and to judge the bad as interference with the desired good.

There is no compelling introspective or perceptive pattern to think that the mammal body is incapable of dealing with unwanted pain in various ways. A rational animal would feel pain or disability, attempt to identify its source of cause, and act to eliminate the source of cause to restore vital-pleasure. Therefore humans instinctually desire to gain and keep prudence: the ability to govern action by the use of reason. The possession of prudence is good! The surgeon cannot operate on himself so she seeks another surgeon. This simple example means we need others to act like external parents or caregivers in early life and at other times in life to help us regulate our own emotions in pursuit of the good.

Unfortunately (or fortunately because it is the way it must be) human prudence is emergent during early life drama and highly specific to the sensory context. Ideas of cause in the present arise as memories of pleasure, pain, and causal ideas from the individual past experience. No mammal, including humans, is capable of forming exclusively accurate ideas of cause in early life! No mammal has an accurate idea of the causes of vitality or disability in every possible dramatic context! Prudence is emergent in humans but also specific to some dramatic context. So life is a mix of values concerning the desire to gain and keep vitality. We refer to the evaluation of those values in the sensory context using the general terms good or bad.

I amplified all my comprehension of mammal drama by contemplating the Genesis story of the first man and woman in the Garden of Delight where God placed the tree of life and the tree of knowledge of good and evil. The proper interpretation is that the ego or seed of the mammal self has the active attributes of man (the effort to govern action) and the receptive attributes of woman (the woman in the story perceives the sensory context in which the fruit of the tree of knowledge is good). The human body is just like the man and woman who eat from the tree of life and the fruit of the tree of knowledge to incorporate the knowledge of what is good and not good in life.

It may be that humans defend against pain in ways that are harmful to vitality. Addiction and distraction from pain do not help anyone form accurate ideas about the causes of disability and pain but are not to be despised if one has compassion for self and others in the drama. The courage to feel pain and form an accurate idea of its cause may be necessary to gain the knowledge of evil, to develop human compassion for others, and to gain prudence.

I may be an existential masochist who thinks pain is good to gain the full knowledge of evil whereas others think pain is just something to avoid or get rid of or inflict on others for their own pleasure! Once my friends wanted to team-up with me to take the Wealth exam in law school figuring their grades would improve. I kept telling them we had to improve our essay to get an A or A- but they said it would be fine if they took a B or B+. The difference is I could stand more pain when information causes me discomfort it is physical pain for me and that pain often drove me to be better at mind-reading my professors and understanding the correct answers to their test questions.

Subjective utility and rational egoism are based on the idea that each individual is the sole authority on the meaning of good and bad in their own sensory context. In general, we infer that people act to cause the good and avoid the bad in their own judgment even though we might not agree with their values or judgments in the dramatic context. A sadist thinks it is good to inflict pain on others. A masochist thinks it is good to have pain inflicted. If life is necessarily a mix of pleasure and pain then it is not unlike sadomasochism. If humans want to be in control of the drama we can understand the appeal of sadomasochistic patterns in normal life or ritual drama. Many patterns of coercion under police force are inherently sadistic either as part of the social system or part of the moral character of the judges and police officers. The victims of official or justified social sadism suffer like scapegoats in the context of those patterns of drama.